# How do I add a custom script to my package.json file that runs two commands at the same time?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-start

I need to run 2 commands at the same time:

```
1)npm start
2)nodemon server.js
```

the first in

```
/user/MatildeSalamanca_Project/web-app
```

and second in

```
/user/MatildeSalamanca_Project/web-app/src/server
```

It has to be something like this but with their respective directories

```
"run": "react-scripts start node server.js"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this instead

```
"run": "cd /user/MatildeSalamanca_Project/web-app && npm start && cd /user/MatildeSalamanca_Project/web-app/src/server && nodemon server.js"
```